# Is the linear combination of eigenfunctions of a time-independent Hamiltonian also a solution of the time independent Schrodinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Consider a system where the Hamiltonian is time independent, the wavefunction which is say a linear combination of the eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian (with different eigenvalues) is not the solution of the time independent Schrodinger equation (TISE). This wavefunction is in fact a solution of the time dependent Schrodinger equation. My question is why is it so? The system has a time independent Hamiltonian so it should be described by a TISE, why do we get a wavefunction which is solution of the general Schrodinger Equation?

Edit: I should rephrase my question to make it more comprehensible. The linear combination of the eigenfunctions gives solution to the Schrodinger equation. For a system with time independent Hamiltonian this linear combination should be a solution of the TISE. It is not always true(when eigenvalues are not equal). Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing the phrase "time-independent Schrodinger equation", though widely used, can be a cause for confusion because it implies that it is in some sense a different version of the Schrodinger equation, which isn't true.  The Schrodinger equation is a first-order differential equation
$$i\hbar \psi'(t) = \hat H \psi(t) \qquad (\star)$$
where $\psi(t)$, which is an element of whatever Hilbert space underlies your theory, can be loosely thought of as the state of the system at time $t$.  This equation tells you how to evolve your state vector forward in time.

If $\psi(t)$ is an eigenstate of $\hat H$ with eigenvalue $E$, then this equation becomes extremely easy to solve:

$$i\hbar \psi'(t) = \hat H \psi(t) = E\psi(t) \implies \psi(t) = e^{-iEt/\hbar} \psi(0)$$
If $\psi(t)$ is a linear combination of such eigenvectors, then the solution is similarly very simple.  If $\psi(t) = \sum_n c_n(t)  \phi_n$ with $\hat H \phi_n = E_n \phi_n$, then
$$\psi(t) = \sum_n c_n(t) \phi_n =\sum_n e^{-iE_n t/\hbar} c_n(0) \phi_n$$

The fact that $\hat H$ is self-adjoint means that *every* state can be written as a linear combination of its eigenstates$^\ddagger$.  Therefore, in order to understand how to evolve any arbitrary vector forward in time, we need only find the set $\{\phi_n\}$ of eigenvectors of $\hat H$ and then expand the initial vector in terms of them.  From there, time evolution is simple - each eigenvector evolves via the corresponding phase factor $e^{-iE_n t/\hbar}$.

Therefore, we turn our attention to finding all of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $\hat H$.  This requires finding all pairs eigenvector/eigenvalue pairs $\{\phi,E\}$ which are solutions to $\hat H\phi = E\phi$.  Once we have all such solutions, we have all the ammunition we need to evolve state vectors forward in time.  This equation $\hat H\phi = E\phi$ is what we call the time-independent Schrodinger equation, but I really dislike that name.

As you can see, the TISE really of completely different character than $(\star)$ - the former being the eigenvalue equation for the Hamiltonian operator, and the latter telling us how to evolve a general state forward in time.  Solving the TISE is an important and very useful step in solving the "general" Schrodinger equation, but they aren't different versions of the same thing.

---

$^\ddagger$This assumes that the spectrum of $\hat H$ is discrete, and that $\hat H$ is not explicitly time-dependent.  Further complications arise if either of these two assumptions fail, but the spirit of this answer remains the same.

Comment: Does this mean that the eigen value equation of the time-independent Hamiltonian, not the TISE?

Comment: @Physicsfreak I'm afraid I don't understand your question.  Can you rephrase it?

Comment: This equation H^ϕ=Eϕ is what we call the time-independent Schrodinger equation, but I really dislike that name. Can you tell what does this statement mean?

Comment: @Physicsfreak The time-independent Schrodinger equation is just the eigenvalue equation $\hat H\phi = E\phi$.  I don't like that name because it makes it sound like it's a different version of the Schrodinger equation $i\hbar \psi'(t) = \hat H\psi(t)$, when in reality those two equations have very little to do with one another, except for the fact that solving the former is an important step in solving the latter.

Comment: thanks for your comment, it cleared the confusion I had all this time around the SE. Is it possible for you to answer some more doubts regarding the SE?

Comment: @Physicsfreak If you have additional questions, you should ask them separately.